# Convert OSM into shapefile with GeoTools?

Tags: openstreetmap, geotools

Is it possible to convert the OSM file to shapefile with [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/) in Java?

Answer (score 2):

No, geotools concentrates on standards based geographical data. Openstreetmap decided to invent their own incompatible format. Therefore you must use a tool written specifically for openstreetmap to convert to an interoperable format before geotools can help. You might be able to use a java library that can read openstreetmap data to write a geotools datastore but no one has bothered to yet.

Comment: OpenJUMP reads OSM data by utilizing the JOSM library. That might be reusable somehow in other Java GIS projects.

Comment: I use geotools to read shapefile and I use Josm to read osm data and shape file too.

Comment: Maybe you can find some more hints in the OSM wiki about https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles